# how to use setBackgroundDrawable and setBackground?

Tags: java, android

(inside `getView` of List)
I create `StateListDrawable` dynamically and use it in `setBackgroundDrawable()`:

```
convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);
```

but this is depricated!!! If I use this:

```
convertView.setBackground(stateListDrawable);
```

my app crashed.(convertView is RelativeLayout) also same crash for `convertView.setBackgroundResource`
Can you tell me what I should use?

Comment: the crash is caused by an Throwable thrown, but what Throwable it is, you only know since you have not post a trace dump

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    setBackground();
} else {
    setBackgroundDrawable();
}
```